# How to stop the inner action from bubbling to the outer link-to helper?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars

**When** clicking the "edit" to trigger the action "edit":

```
  {{#link-to "pages.show" page class="list-group-item"}}
    {{page.name}}
    <span class="badge" {{action "edit" page preventDefault=false}}>edit</span>
  {{/link-to}}
```

**Then** the action is triggered (e.g. the edit page is opened), but in the next second the link-to redirect is done so I end up on the "pages.show" route.

**Expected**: Solely the action "edit" is invoked and the click event(?) is not "bubbled" to the link-to helper.

**Side notes** Ember 2.2 is used and the template above is part of a component.

PS: I red that using *preventDefault=false* inside an action would stop this type of behavior - but obviously the link-to helper gets the information from somewhere else.

Comment: You seem to be misusing `link-to`. Can you expand on your use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is called `event bubbling`. You can disable it by using `bubbles=false` inside your `action` helper, so your click event won't bubble up to the `link-to` element

```
{{#link-to "pages.show" page class="list-group-item"}}
  {{page.name}}
  <span class="badge" {{action "edit" page bubbles=false}}>edit</span>
{{/link-to}}
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_event-propagation

`preventDefault` is a different thing, when setting `preventDefault` to false, you allow the default browser action of the DOM event.

Comment: I believe `link-to` will still trigger the click handler with your solution, because it's the DOM click event that's bubbling.

Comment: thanks dude. despite @locks doughts using bubbles=false on the action helper worked (in chrome).